# nc -v -w 1 111.111.111.111 -z 22 returns port 22 (tcp) timed out: Operation now in progress

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh, firewall, port

Encountering a strange problem on my Ubuntu machine, trying connecting to 111.111.111.111 (example ip)

via SSH fails.

When trying to connect from other win machine its works.

I don't have a firewall on the machine and i can ping 111.111.111.111 and get success response

Trying to ssh (using -vvv) to it get a connection timeout response.

Running the command :

```
nc -v -w 1 111.111.111.111 -z 22
```

returns :

```
nc: connect to 111.111.111.111 port 22 (tcp) timed out: Operation now in progress
```

Running nc command from my working win machine :

```
C:\nc>nc -v -w 1 XXXXXXXXX  -z 22
DNS fwd/rev mismatch: XXXXXXXXX != 289472-XXXXXXXXX
XXXXXXXXX [111.111.111.111] 22 (ssh): open
```

Any ideas what can point to my problem ?

Comment: How do you connect from the win machine? Ssh with putty or similar or another method? Are you sure you connect to port 22?

Comment: and that nc command from the win machine?

Comment: from win machine im using putty to connect or winScp and using port 22

Comment: add nc command out put from win machine to question , thanks

Comment: Have you seen this Web page? http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1544440